# how to expose ports for an angular application in docker

Tags: angular, docker

I want to start a docker image and then go into the browser and the angular application should work out of the box.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM node_net_angular
WORKDIR /source

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT ["ng", "serve"]
```

I do

```
docker build -t test01 .
```

and everything builds correctly. Now i do

```
docker run  test01
```

the console shows me to open localhost:4200, but this doesnt show anything.

Is there a step i forgot?

Thank you

EDIT:

I can just go straight into the folder, type ng serve and everything works. I copy straight everything into my docker image. running ng serve also doesnt produce any error.

I tried running

```
docker run -p 4200:4200 test01
```

but this also doesnt show the website

EDIT: i found the problem. The problem is the entrypoint. If you do this instead

```
CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

it works fine

Comment: You need to use the -p flag to map ports (something like `docker run -p 4200:4200`). Theres [a guide on Medium](https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/your-angular-apps-as-docker-containers-471f570a7f2) that should help

Comment: this is not working unfortunately. I updated the description too

Comment: The flag must be placed before the image name...

Comment: oh yes ofc, but it still doesnt work

Comment: Worked for me after adding `--host 0.0.0.0`. I was trying to run an Angular app from a docker container (e.g. `npm start -- --host 0.0.0.0`)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `ng serve` in a production Docker container because it invokes a development HTTP server, not secure at all, just meant to test the app locally. That's why the command `ng serve --prod` triggers the following warning:

```
**************************************************************************************** 
This is a simple server for use in testing or debugging Angular applications locally. It hasn't been reviewed for security issues.

DON'T USE IT FOR PRODUCTION!
****************************************************************************************
```

I'll give you an example of a Dockerfile wrapping an Angular app with a Nginx HTTP server (one of the two most widely used servers):

```
FROM node:10.13.0-stretch as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g --unsafe-perm @angular/cli@latest
COPY ./ /app/
ARG configuration=production
RUN ng build --prod --build-optimizer=true --aot=true --output-hashing=all --extract-css=true --named-chunks=false --vendor-chunk=true

FROM nginx:1.14.1

# Add application files
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/name-of-your-app/ /var/www/html
COPY --from=build-stage /app/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf 
COPY --from=build-stage /app/nginx/site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 

RUN touch /var/run/nginx.pid && \
    chown -R www-data: /etc/nginx/ && \
    chown -R www-data: /var/run/nginx.pid && \
    chown -R www-data: /var/cache/nginx && \
    chown -R www-data: /var/www/html

USER www-data

#Expose the port
EXPOSE 8080

STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This creates two containers, the first one installs the CLI and builds the app, the second one copies files from the "build container" to its folder served by an Nginx HTTP server, then the first container gets destroyed.

This assumes you have proper `nginx.conf` and `site.conf` in a `nginx` folder that hold your certificate configuration.
You could also use Apache as an HTTP server.